# How to solve angular error "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript' "?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am getting these error while `ng serve`.

I have also tried below code. But getting same error

```
npm install -g typescript
```

[image]

**Error in text form**

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\angular\axen>ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- D:\xampp\htdocs\angular\axen\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\JIGNES~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-p0biUM\angular-errors.log" for further details.

D:\xampp\htdocs\angular\axen>npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
+ typescript@4.2.4
updated 1 package in 2.405s

D:\xampp\htdocs\angular\axen>ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- D:\xampp\htdocs\angular\axen\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Jignesh-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\JIGNES~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-dny752\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Here my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "axen",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^11.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^24.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.5.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.5.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^2.0.0",
    "acorn": "^8.0.4",
    "angular-gauge": "^4.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "mat-progress-buttons": "^9.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.6",
    "ng-click-outside": "^7.0.1",
    "ng-image-fullscreen-view": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-custom-validators": "^11.0.1",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-gauge": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.13.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json?

Comment: I post my package.json file fine i just purchase new theme from themeforest.

Comment: Please copy the errors from your console to the question as text, rather than providing a screenshot of the text. Search engines and people with visual impairments can't read the text from the image.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer by @Devang Patel. Difference is you have to install it in globally and then you may have to set installed path in environment variables.

Try this,

1.Delete the typescript folder in node_modules.

2.`npm install -g typescript` and `npm link typescript`

If this is not working,
uninstall angular-cli globally, run npm cache clean and reinstall cli.
Then repeat the same steps(1 and 2) again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete typescript folder from your node_modules and reinstall it by **"npm install typescript"** command. Still it does not work then try to link it by command **"npm link typescript"**